# EJS Template not rendering data while JSON object is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have an issue rendering data in an EJS-template. The Object with data is present on the page but when I try to show a specific part of the data it won't render (like recept.title).

**Router**

```
router.get("/:slug", function(req, res) {
  Recept.find({ slug: req.params.slug})
    .exec(function(err, foundRecept) {
      if(err || !foundRecept) {
        req.flash("error", "Recept niet gevonden");
        res.redirect("back");
      } else {
        res.render("recepten/recept", { recept: foundRecept });
      }
    });
});
```

When I render the whole object it will render (as shown below).

**HTML File**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="card-img-top">
            //this doesn't render
            <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="<%= recept.image %>"
                alt="<%= recept.title %>"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
            <h1 class="h3"><%= recept.title %></h1>
            <p>
                //this will render the JSON object
                <%= recept %> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Regards Jason

Comment: can you include the object

Comment: I have found the issue. The .find function returns an array and I didn't add the index after foundRecept. But still thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

index.js

```js
const express = require("express")
const path=require("path");
const app = express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
// being rendered res.render()


const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var foundRecept=[{"title":"mango"},{"title":"apple"}]
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/" + "index.html", { recept: foundRecept });
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-9">
     
      <div class="card-title">
        <% for(var i=0; i < recept.length; i++) { %>
          <h1 class="h3"><%= recept[i].title %></h1>
        <% } %>
          
          
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```